# Extend website via styles

Tags: gitbook

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong, but I have the following Problem:

I have a folder with some `.md` files including `SUMMARY.md`and `README.md`.
I also have a `localtheme` folder with some changes in the HTML. 
`book.json`looks like this:

```
"theme": "./localtheme",
"gitbook": ">=2.0.0",
"styles": {
  "website": "styles/website.css"
}
```

I have added a `styles/website.css` into the `localtheme` folder.

Now my gitbook has the changes I made in the localtheme folder EXCEPT the additional style changes in `styles/website.css`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while I found the problem:

```
"theme": "./localtheme"
```

is responsible for the complete layout of your gitbook. If you want to add new styles via

```
"styles": {
  "website": "styles/website.css" 
}
```

you need to delete the `theme` line or else it won't work.

This way you can add styles easily and stay up to date with the new theme changes